# How to use nltk.cluster.kmeans.KMeansClusterer for clustering sentences

Tags: python

I am new to python. Can anyone tell me how to use nltk.cluster.kmeans.KMeansClusterer for clustering senences. And in place of euclidean distance,can i use levensthein distance?

Comment: Have a look to this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123060/clustering-a-long-list-of-strings-words-into-similarity-groups

Comment: but this example does not use k means. I need to use Levenshtein distance with k means for clustering sentences. And also that example is for clustering single words. but i need to cluster sentences

Comment: example of sentences which i need to cluster is                   
sentences = ["highly recommend series anyone yearning watch grown up television Complex characters plots keep one totally involved Thank Amazon Prime",
             "Mysteries interesting tension between Robson tall blond good always believable seemed uncomfortable",
             "beats watching blank screen do n't seem tune comedy today",
             "many episodes series pretty-much skip through try find description something think 's kind crap shoot whether 'll entertained"]